# Get the index of a child of the root treeview to add a child

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a treeview `tvEinfuegen`. My goal is to add a child to a node in it's root not at index `0` called `test` by clicking on it. That works. But clicking on `test` trying to add a child to `test` with the same method returns `0` as `CurrentNode.Index`. I presume, the index is not for the whole treeview, but starts new for each new child.

Yet how do I get the appropriate index to add `child2` below `child1` when clicking on `child1` instead of putting it as a child of `root`?

My code

```
private void tvEinfuegen_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewHitTestInfo info = tvEinfuegen.HitTest(e.Location);    
    if (info.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.Label)
    {
        TreeNode CurrentNode = e.Node;
        if (CurrentNode != null)
        {
            string ordnername = "Test";
            if (ordnername != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(CurrentNode.Index);
                tvEinfuegen.Nodes[CurrentNode.Index].Nodes.Add(ordnername);
                tvEinfuegen.Nodes[CurrentNode.Index].Expand();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WinForms? WPF? Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be making it more complicated than you need to. Your user has clicked on a node; your code is experiencing a node click so `e.Node` would be the node they clicked on, and if you want to add something to its child `.Nodes` collection just add it via the `e.Node.Nodes` rather than trying to index things or reference the treeview, root node, index.. etc..:

```
private void tvEinfuegen_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewHitTestInfo info = tvEinfuegen.HitTest(e.Location);    
    if (info.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.Label)
    {
        if (e.Node!= null)
            e.Node.Nodes.Add("test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
tvEinfuegen.Nodes[CurrentNode.Index].Nodes.Add(ordnername);
tvEinfuegen.Nodes[CurrentNode.Index].Expand();
```

with

```
CurrentNode.Nodes.Add(ordnername);
CurrentNode.Expand();
```

and it works

Comment: yep, that's pretty much my assessment too